# Opening Multiple Accounts In Outlook 2016

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I'm trying to setup another account in Outlook, besides my primary, (this is another account through Account Settings > Email > New, not a shared mailbox) and I cannot get it to work. I can add the account just fine (autodiscover works and I get all the green checks) but when I try to open it I get an error "The set of folders cannot be opened. The file  is not an Outlook data file (.ost)". If I remove the account and add it back again with cached mode disabled I get the error "The set of folders cannot be opened. Network problems are preventing connection to Microsoft Exchange"
I'm using the C2R version of Outlook but I've tried it with the MSI version and it's the same thing.
Both accounts are Exchange Online accounts. Is this supported? Are other people able to add multiple EXO accounts to a single Outlook profile?

Comment: I don't deal with EXO but if I were working with previous versions I would make sure I had given myself full access permissions so that I could add the extra account.

Comment: This is for adding another account (using the account owner credentials) not adding a shared mailbox. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: We have different definitions of "shared mailbox". Exchange has the term for a type of mailbox called shared mailbox. Then there's granting yourself access to someone else's mailbox. If you have userA with mailbox and userB with another mailbox. You want to be able to add userB to your outlook so you can see its contents. You give yourself permissions to view his mailbox while logged in with your own creds. This is what I'm referring to and it's not a shared mailbox. It remains userB's mailbox but you can view it. Without full access permissions you get the error message you've mentioned.

Comment: Fair. Yes I'm referring to accessing a mailbox using the owners account. Just having both in a single Outlook profile.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: adding two different Exchange Online mailboxes in the profile. Both of them work as expected.

Please ensure the second mailbox is working when setting up it in a single profile.